# GWT has never heard of java.io.BufferedReader?

Tags: gwt, java-io

When I build the war file for deployment (ant war), the GWT compiler acts as if it has never heard of java.io.Reader or java.io.BufferedReader.  When I make the development build for devmode (ant javac), they build just fine.  I'm using GWT 2.4.0.  Does anyone know what is going on?

```
   gwtc:
         [java] Compiling module com.foo.Foo
         [java]    Validating newly compiled units
         [java]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:[...]/Foo/src/com/foo/shared/ReaderLineIterator.java'
         [java]          [ERROR] Line 13: No source code is available for type java.io.BufferedReader; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [java]          [ERROR] Line 21: No source code is available for type java.io.Reader; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [java]    [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files

    BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: You cannot save files in the client-side, that's why GWT doesn't and will never implement the java.io package.... the best you can do to persist data on the client is use cookies.

Comment: @Renato Actually there's support for client-side persistence which is implemented on top of the HTML5 storage: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage Similar to cookies but not the same thing.

Comment: @Baqueta Oh, thanks for the link... I haven't had much time yet looking at HTML5 because we can't really use it yet as most users we have still have old versions of IE and similar crap... but I will check this out.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with saving files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the complete package `java.io` is supported by GWT.

See the [JRE Emulation Reference](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation) for details

Comment: Ah, I think the link you want is this: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation

Answer (score 2):

The client-side of GWT does not have access to the whole Java API. java.io is one of them. 
When you run or compile it will give you `did you forget to inherit a required module?` error. But you can definitely use it on the server-side of GWT. You can find the list of classes that can be used at client-side [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation).